# java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: Data array too small (should be > 388799 )

Tags: image, converters, bufferedimage, xuggler, xuggle

I am trying to do some image manipulation using `IConverter` class which is included in **Xuggle** library to convert the images from `IVideoPicture` type to `BufferedImage` type but am encountering the error in the title.

Here is my code:

```
BufferedImage orgnlimage = new BufferedImage(Picture.getWidth(), Picture.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(orgnlimage, IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24);
orgnlimage = converter.toImage(Picture); // Exception on this line
```

The dimensions of the image in question, is **360x360**.

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: Data array too small (should be > 388799 )
    at sun.awt.image.ByteComponentRaster.verify(ByteComponentRaster.java:947)
    at sun.awt.image.ByteComponentRaster.<init>(ByteComponentRaster.java:201)
    at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.<init>(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:191)
    at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.<init>(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:113)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:980)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.video.BgrConverter.toImage(BgrConverter.java:195)
    at xuggler.Encrypt.main(Encrypt.java:53)
    at xuggler.DecodeAndSaveAudioVideo.main(DecodeAndSaveAudioVideo.java:141)
```

My Second attemp :

```
public IVideoPicture main(IVideoPicture Picture) throws NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException
{ 
        int width = Picture.getWidth();
        int height = Picture.getHeight();
        long timestamp = Picture.getTimeStamp();

BufferedImage orgnlimage = videoPictureToImage(Picture);


        byte[] orgnlimagebytes =toByte(orgnlimage); 
        byte[] encryptedbytes = encrypt(orgnlimagebytes, "abc");
        //System.out.println(encryptedbytes.length);

        BufferedImage encryptedimage = toImage(encryptedbytes, width, height);   

        String desc = ConverterFactory.findDescriptor(encryptedimage);
       IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(desc, Picture);


        IVideoPicture Pic = converter.toPicture(encryptedimage, timestamp);

        return Pic;

}
```

and the stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:363)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:859)
at com.xuggle.xuggler.video.BgrConverter.toPicture(BgrConverter.java:132)
at xuggler.Encrypt.main(Encrypt.java:62)
at xuggler.DecodeAndSaveAudioVideo.main(DecodeAndSaveAudioVideo.java:141)
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace, perhaps? On what line to you get the `RasterFormatException`? Also, what are the dimensions of your image?

Comment: the error is in the last line and the dimensions are aquired from the IPicture Picture

Comment: I meant, what are the dimensions, literally (like 120x120 or similar)? And, you *must* include the stack trace, in the question.

Comment: at xuggler.Encrypt.main(Encrypt.java:53)
 at xuggler.DecodeAndSaveAudioVideo.main(DecodeAndSaveAudioVideo.java:141) @haraldK

Comment: Okay... Fixed your question for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for some reason, the Xuggler `BgrConverter.toImage()` method tries to create a raster around a `byte` array of size `388799`, which is one byte short... It should have been of size `388800` (`360 * 360 * 3`) for your image in BGR format.

I'd say [file a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/xuggle/issues/list?can=2&q=label%3AType-Defect).

Or try [Humble Video](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video) instead, which seems to kind of a successor to Xuggler.

Comment: Thank you .. honestly i felt a little lost in the situation so i tried another way  to do the job but i got a buffer overflow exception and i did not know how to fix it .. do u have any idea  ?? i will assert it in the question

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: OK i will :)
sir, have you worked on the Xuggler before ??

Comment: No, sorry. But I have worked extensively with `BufferedImage`s in all its flavors and the Java2D API in general. And I looked up the source code for `BgrConverter` before answering. :-)